# how to calculated next excel character sequence which is separated by nth columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In sheet 1, i have some values in 'AC', 'AV', 'BO' columns. These columns actually 17 columns difference. It means AC+17 column= AV, AV+17 column= BO
So i need to show these values in Sheet 2. however i am finding difficulty to export this sequence or address. Because i have another next 50 sequences ending with AMV.

```
CHAR(CODE(A1)+17
```

character calculation is fine only upto CHAR(CODE(A1)+1) which is ending with Z. But i need the sequence upto AMV.

Thanks

Comment: Excel also supports CR notation (column/row number). That would be a solution for your problem.

Comment: I am still finding difficulty to get.. any hints about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you want to do, but assuming that you want to get the values onto Sheet2 in a contiguous block of columns starting in column A try this formula in Sheet 2 Column A and copy across 50 columns:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$L1,0,17*COLUMN())
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.. in order to clarify my question.. forget about Sheets... I want to display my (AC column, 5th row), (AV Column, 5th row) , (BOth column, 5th Row)... so on upto (AMV column, 5th Row)

Comment: so use =OFFSET(Sheet1!$L5,0,17*COLUMN())

Comment: COLUMN NAME Values
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
. 
. 
. 
. 
AC 29
AD 30
AE 31
. 
. 
AV 47
  For example i have information.. while using your formula =OFFSET($AC1,0,17*COLUMN()).. it is giving me 0.. but i am expecting 47....

Comment: =OFFSET($AC1,0,5*COLUMN())

Comment: My requirements satisfied now with code =OFFSET(Sheet1!$AC6,0,17*1) .. then the next one is =OFFSET(Sheet1!$AC6,0,17*2).... how can i do generic formula out of this....

Comment: What columns are these OFFSET formulas placed in, and are they in adjacent columns?

Comment: So what cell addresses are the formulas placed in?

Comment: OK ... you are copying down, not across so you need to use ROW not COLUMN - try =OFFSET(Sheet1!$AC$6,0,17*(ROW()-2)) in D3 and then copy down.I see you have already reached the same answer!

Answer (score 1):

This may be of no help.  If you want to generate a series of column *ids* starting with **AC**, pick any cell and enter:

```
=LEFT(MID(ADDRESS(1,29+19*(ROWS($1:1)-1)),2,9999),LEN(MID(ADDRESS(1,29+19*(ROWS($1:1)-1)),2,9999))-2)
```

and copy down:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Pick some cell and enter:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$AC6,0,17*COLUMNS($A:A))
```

then copy across.

**EDIT#2:**

To ***freeze the 6*** use:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$AC$6,0,17*COLUMNS($A:A))
```

**EDIT#3:**

If you enter

```
=COLUMNS($A:A)
```

into any cell, it will show ***1***.  If you copy this formula across, the cells should show ***1, 2, 3, ...***  This is also true if you copy

```
=ROWS($1:1)
```

downwards.

Comment: Thanks Gary.. it is really good info. However i am looking for contents of the above series which is column names for me....

Comment: My requirements satisfied now with code =OFFSET(Sheet1!$AC6,0,17*1) .. then the next one is =OFFSET(Sheet1!$AC6,0,17*2).... how can i do generic formula out of this....

Comment: @user2642751  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Sorry... if you enlarge the series it is increasing like below....OFFSET(Sheet1!$AC6,0,17*COLUMNS($A:A))   OFFSET(Sheet1!$AC7,0,17*COLUMNS($A:A))   OFFSET(Sheet1!$AC8,0,17*COLUMNS($A:A))   But i need in series like below.   OFFSET(Sheet1!$AC6,0,17*1)   OFFSET(Sheet1!$AC6,0,17*2)         OFFSET(Sheet1!$AC6,0,17*3)          OFFSET(Sheet1!$AC6,0,17*4)

Comment: Almost done... AC$6 works fine.. only thins COLUMNS($A:A) is 1... however how i increase it 2, 3 ......50 times....

Comment: @user2642751  see my **EDIT#3**

Comment: Thanks a lot it works fine for me..............this is what i wanted...my final answer is below....=OFFSET(Sheet1!AC$6,0,17*ROWS($1:1))

Comment: @user2642751  Good job !!